# Artifactory maven plugin fails to deploy

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I'm tring to use the `artifactory-maven-plugin` to upload a maven build to my artifactory server. Uploading with the jfrog cli works, so it seems not a permission problem.
Here is my pom.xml:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>publish</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployProperties>
                            <gradle>awesome</gradle>
                            <review.team>qa</review.team>
                        </deployProperties>
                        <contextUrl>http://vserver1.craftwater.de:8081/artifactory</contextUrl>
                        <username>myUser</username>                         
                        <password>mySecret</password>
                        <excludePatterns>*-tests.jar</excludePatterns>
                        <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                        <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The result of `mvn deploy` is an IllegalArgutementException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target repository cannot be empty
at org.jfrog.build.client.DeployDetails$Builder.build(DeployDetails.java:119)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.addDeployableArtifact(BuildInfoRecorder.java:604)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.addArtifactsToCurrentModule(BuildInfoRecorder.java:533)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.addFilesToCurrentModule(BuildInfoRecorder.java:477)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.finalizeAndAddModule(BuildInfoRecorder.java:464)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.finalizeModule(BuildInfoRecorder.java:392)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.projectSucceeded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:74)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:91)
... 16 more
```

Is this a bug or do I do something wrong?

Artifactory version: Artifactory OSS 4.11.1 rev 40241

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your plugin configuration is missing the publisher tag. You can use the Maven Artifactory Plugin reference guide and also this example project:

https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/artifactory-maven-plugin-example

I hope this helps.

Comment: not sure i can recommend the artifactory plugin. doing the deploy without it takes about 6 minutes for me and then when i switch to the plugin, it's about 4 minutes. not sure exactly why