# Publish debug & release to artifactory

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I'm using Android Studio and desperately trying to get gradle to publish both my debug & release aar's to artifactory with separate repoKeys. Preferably as two separate tasks. I have read this [excellent guide](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/13/artifactory2/), but I don't want to change my gradle file each time in order to deploy.

I can easily create two pom files, but have not managed to make the artifactory plugin dynamic enough to switch my two rep keys.

I feel this is the closest I've come but it's not quite there:

```
String art_repo = ''

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://www.myjfrogrepo.com'

    publish {
        repository {
            // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            repoKey = "${art_repo}"
```

I have then created a custom task which sets the art_repo variable.

```
task debugPublishTojFrog {
    group "Publishing"
    art_repo = 'libs-snapshot-local'
    art_publicationName = 'debugAar'

    doLast {
        println "Successfully published ${art_repo} to jFrog"
    }
}
debugPublishTojFrog.finalizedBy artifactoryPublish
```

This responds with the error

```
Target repository cannot be empty
```

This leads me to think the repoKey is set at build time and not at run time because my custom task's changes seem to be ignored.

Any suggestions really would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283163/6309, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39849226/6309.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard way to do this in gradle is to test for the version you are about to publish.

This is exactly what the guide you link to advocates:

```
repoKey = libraryVersion.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? 'libs-snapshot-local' : 'libs-release-local'
```

What is wrong with this solution?

Edit: If the problem lies with having to change gradle or the gradle.properties file, why not use properties from the command line.

```
repoKey = project.hasProperty('releaseVersion') ? 'libs-release-local' : 'libs-snapshot-local'
```

And build your snapshot with

```
gradle build
```

And build your release with

```
gradle build -PreleaseVersion=1.0.0-GA
```

You can also use this releaseVersion property at several other locations, like your software metadata, your publication information...

Comment: Because this involves changing gradle, specifically the version name, every time I want to switch between a snapshot or a release build. I want to be able to deploy the exact same code once to snapshot and once to release.

Comment: I am confused as to why you don't just put the version in a properties file and change it there. Or do you want your source code to not vary at all? If that is the case, your only option is to pass it as a parameter to the CLI, I added this case in my reply.

Comment: Yes I think you are right, this is the only way to achieve this. It's a shame, I don't think this is a "clean" solution but at least I've now got it working. Thanks for your continued support.